# React Native iap - requestSubscription method returns a true instead of SubscriptionPurchase object

Tags: react-native, react-native-iap

I am using react-native-iap V8.1.1 and react-native V0.65.1
After calling requestSubscription method The log will be like "iap data: true" but as it is explained in the react-native-iap documentation I should recieve my data as a SubscriptionPurchase object.

Here is my code:

```
RNIap.requestSubscription({ sku: chosen }).then((data) => {
          console.log('iap data:', data);
          user.upgradeUser({
            productId: data.productId,
            purchaseToken: Platform.select({ ios: data.transactionReceipt, android: data.purchaseToken }),
          }).then(() => {
            setloading(false);
            RNIap.finishTransaction(data, false);
            navigation.navigate('PlusCeleb');
          }).catch(() => {
            setloading(false);
          });
        }).catch((err) => {
          setloading(false);
          console.log('iap err', err);
          Message(
            err.message,
            'warning',
          );
        });
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

this issue was fixed in version 12.3.2 update your library